# How to understand end tag/loop relations in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, if-statement, while-loop

World!
New to all types of programming, so maybe I'm not understanding how loops/if/ else work in general?
My problem is this:

Any time I run this program, it runs fine, except for the **exiting part**, aka saying "BYE".
Whenever I say "BYE" grandma responds with "NO, NOT SINCE 1943" *then* the program exits. 
My problem is that If I move the `statement = gets.chomp` to anywhere else besides the inside of the two `ends` it infinite loops, or gives me the same exiting issue.

This is the code I am using.

```
puts "Talk to grandma!"
puts "To stop talking to Grandma say 'BYE'"
sleep 1
puts "Remember grandma has bad hearing. You might need to Yell!"

statement = ""
while statement != "BYE"

    statement =gets.chomp
 if statement != statement.upcase
    puts "WHAT?! SPEAK UP!"

else
    year = rand(1940..1955).to_s
    puts "NO, NOT SINCE " + year

end
end
```

**Problem: Exits when "BYE" is spoken, but only after saying "NO, NOT SINCE" etc etc**

*However* when I change the code around to:

```
puts "Talk to grandma!"
puts "To stop talking to Grandma say 'BYE'"
sleep 1
puts "Remember grandma has bad hearing. You might need to Yell!"

statement = gets.chomp
while statement != "BYE"

  if statement != statement.upcase
    puts "WHAT?! SPEAK UP!"

 else
     year = rand(1940..1955).to_s
     puts "NO, NOT SINCE " + year

   end
statement= gets.chomp
end
```

The program then works PERFECTLY.

Doesn't the loop end when it says end? How would the `statement = gets.chomp` in the bottom get included in the loop if it already ended? Or am I misunderstanding it, and the first end relates to the if/else, and the SECOND end refer to the "ending of the loop"?

I'm self learning with Chris Pines Learn to Program using Ruby, but... all it says is "Everything in the loop before `end` gets repeated."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Former code:

```
while statement != "BYE"
    statement =gets.chomp
    # if-else validation
end
```

Which means that you do these steps:

1. Read user input
2. Validate it with your `if-else` statement
3. Continue with loop.
4. Validate it against the `while` loop.

Latter code:

```
statement= gets.chomp
while statement != "BYE"
    # if-else validation
    statement= gets.chomp
end
```

Here you read user input, then start the `while` loop.:

1. Validate it against the `while` loop.
2. Validate it with your `if-else` statement.
3. Read user input.
4. Continue with loop.

The relevant part is **when** you decide to validate the user input to continue inside the `while` loop and what you do before or after that validation. Note that this doesn't belong to Ruby but to any programming language. The logic is which matters in this case.

In short, the order **matters**.

---

> first end relates to the if/else, and the SECOND end refer to the "ending of the loop"?

Yes, this is entirely correct. This is easier to understand when you indent the code:

```
while statement != "BYE"               # <----.
    statement =gets.chomp              #      |
    if statement != statement.upcase   # <-.  |
        puts "WHAT?! SPEAK UP!"        #   |  |
    else                               #   |  |
        year = rand(1940..1955).to_s   #   |  |
        puts "NO, NOT SINCE " + year   #   |  |
    end                                # <-.  |
end                                    # <----.
```

---

You could also have the loop in this form:

```
while true
    statement = gets.chomp
    # the statement below will be executed only if the condition on the right is met
    break if statement == 'BYE'
    # if-else condition
end
```

Comment: Thank you SO much! With the use of the arrows I finally understand WHAT is going on, where it's jumping around, and how I can manipulate the order to make it work correctly.

Comment: You're welcome. And don't forget to indent the code, it will help readability of the code and to spot some problems like missing `end` or similar bugs.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your script. The following is (in my opinion) easier to read and debug, and works in casual testing with Ruby 2.1.2:

```
puts "Talk to grandma!"
puts "To stop talking to Grandma say 'BYE'"
puts "Remember grandma has bad hearing. You might need to Yell!"

loop do
  case gets.chomp
  when 'BYE'
    break
  when /[[:lower:]]/
    puts 'WHAT?! SPEAK UP!'
  else
    puts "NO, NOT SINCE #{rand 1940..1955}"
  end
end
```

Comment: I appreciate your more streamlined script, however my problem is not necessarily making it more beautiful, it's that I have apparently not understood the basics. Looking at your new code, I have not learned do/case/when/break etc so it looks like Chinese(and I only speak English/Japanese). 

Once I learn the basics, I will definitely review your code to see how I can improve!